# Need to pass previous build results in HTML test report in playwright

Tags: javascript, typescript, ui-automation, playwright, playwright-test

I am trying to show for each test case the previous build status of the test case. I am trying to achieve using test.info() in playwright. But test.info() cannot be accessed from onTestEnd in playwright. I will need to fetch the previous build data from jenkins. Any inputs please.

[Expected Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DEty9.png)

I tried storing the build data in gsheet and access them on each run. But it seems to be very complex. Any ways to achieve this easily?

Answer (score 0):

### Use Allure Report

You may use [allure html report](https://www.npmjs.com/package/allure-playwright) for this.Once installed, this can be configured in playwright config file as below:

playwright.config.ts

```
{
  reporter: [["line"], ["allure-playwright"]];
}
```

Or pass the same value via command line:

```
npx playwright test --reporter=line,allure-playwright
```

Once configured,you may generate html reports and keep the tests history as below:

#### Keeping Test History

A test report generated by Allure can not only display data about the latest test launch, but also help you compare it with the data from previous reports. To do so, Allure can keep a history or previous reports.

[image]

In a tests report with the history included, you can:

- see what statuses did a test have previously (see [Details panel → History tab](https://allurereport.org/docs/gettingstarted-details-panel/#history-tab)),
- find tests that changed status since last report (see [Sorting and filtering → Filter tests by marks](https://allurereport.org/docs/gettingstarted-sorting-and-filtering/#filter-tests-by-marks)),
- see how specific values change over time (see [Graphs](https://allurereport.org/docs/gettingstarted-graphs/)).